# When minimum value of $x$ which is $p$ is one of factor of $10^x - 1$ is $a$.......

Tags: number-theory

When minimum value of $x$ which is $p$ is  one of factor of $(10^x - 1)$ is $a$. Naturally, $(10^a - 1)$ is divisible by $p$.
      ($p$ is prime, $a$ is whole number)

If so, $(10^a - 1)$ is not divisible by $p^2$?($7 \leq p$)

For example, $(10^6 - 1)$ is divisible by $7$ but it is not divisible by  $7^2$.

Comment: Is p a prime here??

Comment: @THELONEWOLF. Yes, p is prime.

Comment: It's not clear to me, you have used a,p,x in a bad manner.Write the question such that everyone can understand it.If it is a homework question than don't try to add something meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. After $p=3$, the first counterexample is $p=487$:
$$
ord_{487}(10) = 486 = ord_{487^2}(10)
$$

Comment: You are first :)

Comment: I'm so glad with your kindness!

Comment: There are no other counterexamples before $10000$. The next counterexample is probably $56598313$. See http://oeis.org/A045616.

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27579/is-the-smallest-primitive-root-modulo-p-a-primitive-root-modulo-p2/27619 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime.

Answer (score 1):

Try p =3 - it is contrexample ^_^

Comment: I'm sorry.... I didn't put a condition.....